# Book where it's a new future ice age and they worship Apple

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia, future

It was like a Sci fi book where there was a new ice age, everything was iced over but the humans found old Apple products and thought the old humans worshipped God Apple, the main character was a girl, I think someone close to her had died in the ice, but she was investigating and it looked like her tribe/ family? Had killed him instead? I've been looking for it for ages.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this ***[Relic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17262735-relic)*** (2013) by Heather Terrell...? It's the first book in the *[Books of Eva](https://www.goodreads.com/series/97220-books-of-eva)* series.

> [image: Front cover of "Relic" (2013) by Heather Terrell.]

According to this [review](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/dec/20/review-relic-heather-terrell), the story is set in a time when the rest of the world has been flooded and frozen over. The protagonist, Eva, is an 18-year-old girl whose brother died in a climbing accident.

> **Relic follows the story of Eva, an eighteen year old girl who lives in a time where the rest of the world has been flooded and frozen over. Her brother dies in a climbing accident** and Eva decides to take his place to compete for the title of Archon. The trial takes place in an icy plain where they must unearth relics from their past (our present).

Another [review](https://rhapsodyinbooks.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/review-of-relic-by-heather-terrell/) notes that the polar ice caps melted 250 years earlier, and that Eva lives in a medieval-style community called the New North that is largely ignorant of Earth's history prior to that catastrophe.

> **The New North is the Arctic island home of the only survivors of global flooding after the polar ice caps melted some 250 years before this story takes place. New North is ruled by a Triad (mandated by The Gods, needless to say), consisting of a Lexor (sort of a police chief), a Basilikon (priest) and Archon (government administrator). The polity relies on two sacred texts, The Praebulum and The Lex. The Lex sounds suspiciously like the Bible, but the New North people don’t know that, because they don’t know what the Bible is.**
>
> **One reason they are uninformed is because New North has been organized in the form of a medieval society, without access to much knowledge of the past.**

The people of the New North believe that mankind's prior use of technology angered the gods and that the gods flooded the Earth to wipe the slate clean, similar to the biblical Genesis flood. They associate mankind's past sins with big name brands such as Tylenol, Coca Cola and Mastercard, and are under the impression that mankind once worshipped a false god called Apple. Their beliefs are informed by old devices they've found whilst digging through the ice to find 'relics.'

> **The people have been taught that technology is what angered the gods and brought their wrath down on earth.** The people of New North know only what they are taught about the time before:
>
> > *“We of the New North need Archons to show us the perils of our ways before the Healing – the abuse of our Father Earth that yielded the Healing floods. We need to learn again of the hunger for Tylenols that poisoned our minds; the thirst for Cokes that weakened our bodies; the greed for MasterCards that toppled our rules. **All this evil spawned from the worship of the false god Apple….**”*
>
> Needless to say, New North is not sponsoring Black Friday sales each year. What they do host each year, however, is a game in which **eighteen-year-olds compete in The Testing to serve in the Triad. As part of the competition, they must climb down a glacier and dig through the ice to find relics: leftovers from antediluvian times. The most valued relics are of course the Evil Apple devices.** (Not much has changed in that respect…) There are always relics to be found; the more critical part of the Testing (besides surviving, of course), is to construct the best Chronicle about the found relic, describing how the relic led to mankind’s fall.

According to this [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/753401012), it eventually transpires that Eva's brother, Eamon, was murdered, rather than having died in an accident.

> RELIC begins with a treacherous mountain climb and a betrayal, resulting in the death of Eamon. I loved this beginning, and was sad that **it took a long time to get to what I thought would happen earlier: other characters realizing Eamon was murdered.**

You can read a preview of the book [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Relic/55JiDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: "once worshipped a false god called Apple" the author isn't going for subtlety, is she?

Comment: @xLeitix. Well, Aldous Huxley wasn't either.